# Error: useMyContext must be used within a MyContextProvider

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am trying to make the Header component visible on all pages but importing it in layout.tsx file but it shows me this error

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: useMyContext must be used within a MyContextProvider

```
const context = useContext(MyContext);
   if (!context) {
   throw new Error("useMyContext must be used within a MyContextProvider");
            ^
   }
   return context;
   };
```

this is context.tsx file where the MyContextProvider is defined

```
"use client";
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState,
  ReactNode,
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
} from "react";

export type Product = {
  id: number;
  attributes: {
    title: string;
    price: number | null;
    description: string;
    createdAt: number;
    link: string;
    image: {
      data: any;
    };
    keywords: string;
    categories: {
      data: Category[];
    };
    sub_categories: {
      data: SubCategory[];
    };
  };
};

export type Category = {
  id: number;
  attributes: {
    title: string;
    products: {
      data: Product[];
    };
    sub_categories: {
      data: SubCategory[];
    };
  };
};

export type SubCategory = {
  id: number;
  attributes: {
    title: string;
    description: string | null;
    image: {
      data: any;
    };
    categories: {
      data: Category[];
    };
    products: {
      data: Product[];
    };
  };
};

interface MyContextValue {
  categories: Category[];
  setCategories: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Category[]>>;
  products: Product[];
  setProducts: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Product[]>>;
  subcategories: SubCategory[];
  setSubCategories: Dispatch<SetStateAction<SubCategory[]>>;
}

const MyContext = createContext<MyContextValue | undefined>(undefined);

const initialValue: Category[] = [];
const initialProductValue: Product[] = [];
const initialSubCategoryValue: SubCategory[] = [];

export const MyContextProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState<Category[]>(initialValue);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>(initialProductValue);
  const [subcategories, setSubCategories] = useState<SubCategory[]>(
    initialSubCategoryValue
  );

  const contextValue: MyContextValue = {
    categories,
    setCategories,
    products,
    setProducts,
    subcategories,
    setSubCategories,
  };

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useMyContext = (): MyContextValue => {
  const context = useContext(MyContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useMyContext must be used within a MyContextProvider");
  }
  return context;
};
```

And this is layout.tsx

```
"use client";
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { MyContextProvider, useMyContext } from "@/app/utils/context";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import Header from "@/components/Header";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });



export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
})
 {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { categories } = useMyContext();

  return (
    <MyContextProvider>
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <link
            rel="icon"
            href="/favicon.ico"
            type="image/x-icon"
            sizes="any"
          />
        </head>
        <body className={`bg-white ${inter.className}`}>
          <Header categories={categories} router={router} />
          {children}
          <Footer />
        </body>
      </html>
    </MyContextProvider>
  );
}
```

This is page.tsx if that helps

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import "./globals.css";
import {
  fetchCategories,
  fetchProducts,
  fetchSubCategories,
  fetchProductsBySubcategory,
} from "@/app/utils/api";

import { useMyContext } from "@/app/utils/context";
import { SubCategory } from "@/app/utils/context";
import Header from "@/components/Header";

import ProductCard from "@/components/ProductCard";
import SubCategoryPage from "./category/[subcategory]/page";

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    categories,
    setCategories,
    products,
    setProducts,
    subcategories,
    setSubCategories,
  } = useMyContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    getCategories();
    getProducts();
    getSubcategories();
  }, []);

  const getCategories = () => {
    fetchCategories().then((res) => {
      console.log("Categories:", res);
      setCategories(res.data);
    });
  };

  const getProducts = () => {
    fetchProducts().then((res) => {
      console.log("Products:", res);
      setProducts(res.data);
    });
  };

  const getSubcategories = () => {
    fetchSubCategories().then((res) => {
      console.log("Subcategories:", res);
      setSubCategories(res.data);
    });
  };

  console.log("Products:", products);
  console.log("Categories:", categories);
  console.log("SubCategories:", subcategories);

  return (
    <div className="m-auto">
      <ProductCard products={products} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to be able to display the Header component on all pages

Comment: The provider must be higher up the component tree than the consumer. `Layout` is calling `useMyContext`, but the provider is a *child* of `Layout`. The provider must be a *parent* of `Layout`.